# using jquery picker plugin as editor template for datetime properties

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc

I've found interesting [jquery datetime plugin](http://www.jqueryrain.com/?ixXmZ27b) which I want to set as editor template for all my DateTime properties in my asp.net mvc 5 application.

I know that I should put some code in Shared/EditorTemplate but I dont any further.

Answer (score 1):

**View**

```
@Html.TextboxFor(m => m.PROPERTY, new{ data_field="date",@readonly="readonly"}
<div id="dtBox"></div>

@section scripts{
 @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquerydatetimeplugin") // this is obviously managed in BundleConfig.cs
 $(function()
  {
    $("#dtBox").DateTimePicker();
  });
 }
```

**Layout.cshtml**

```
....
  @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
  @RenderSection("scripts", required: false)
</body>
</html>
```